# variable is showing on dd but not rendering at json resource laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

i have an object like below : this is the result of my dd

```
      #test: \test\test {#1274
                #Test: array:6 [
                  0 => array:2 [
                    "from" => 1631431800
                    "to" => 1631503800
                  ]
                  1 => array:5 [
                    "from" => 1631431800
                    "to" => 1631503800
               
                  ]
        
                ]
              }
              -expired_at: 1631100600
              +"hasTime": false
```

and in my json resource i have returned a simple collection like below :

```
        return $this->collection;
```

now my problem is that i cant see the `hasTime` variable in my return statement on postman and i noticed its a bit different because it has `+` next on it on dd and its in a `" "` mark . so i want to know how can i show this in my result and what is the meaning of that plus and cotations . thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to the quotation below ([From here](https://tighten.co/blog/a-better-dd-for-your-tdd/)):

> Since version 5, Laravel's dd() (and it's cousin, dump(), which
> doesn't halt execution) has relied on Symfony's VarDumper component
> under the hood.

Take a see to the [**Symfony's VarDumper examples and output**](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#dump-examples-and-output).

So maybe the "hasTime" property was removed before the "return statement" (for whatever reason)...